# Show different controls depending on rails collection select (selected) item

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Sorry i couldn't get a better title to my question but hope my explanation will give you guys a better idea of what's going on?

I have a model `Airport` and three other models `West` `East` and `South` that aren't related in anyway only that `Airport` model needs some of the other fields like this form shows.

```
<%= form_for(@airport) do %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:airport_name, AirPortManager.all, etc...) %>
      //AirPortManager is a collection of available airports

    <div class="west-airports" style="display:none;">
        <%= f.collection_select(:airline_name, WestAirlineManager.all, ....) %>
    </div>

    <div class="east-airports" style="display: none;">
        <%= f.collection_select(:airline_name, EastAirlineManager.all, ....) %>
    </div>


    <div class="south-airports" style="display: none;">
        <%= f.collection_select(:airline_name, EastAirlineManager.all, ....) %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

The airport model `validates :airline_name, :presence => true` . Now the problem is with

my javascript. If a user selects airport west in `AirPortManager.all` the `west-airports` div` should be shown and so on. But my validation method airport keeps throwing a required field error for :airline_name and if not that it keeps a value from a previous selection. How can i pass the visible div value to airport parameters or if i select an empty value the previous value shoudn't remain constant. Below is my javascript and hope my question makes sense.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#aiport_manager_aiport_name").change(function(){
                var value = this.value;
                if (value == "West") {
                     $('.west-aiports').show();
                    $('.east-airports').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('.east-airports').hide();
                     $('.south-airports').attr("disabled", true);
                     $('.south-airports').hide();
                    }
                else if (value == "East") {
                    $('.east-airports').show();
                    $('.west-aports').hide();
                    $('.west-airports').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('.south-airports').hide();
                    $('.south-airports').attr("disabled", true);
                    }
                else if (value == "South") {
                    $('.south-aiports').show(); 
                    $('.west-airports').hide();
                    $('.west-airports').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('.east-airports').hide();
                    $('.east-airports').attr("disabled", true);
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

I try and disable the other collection_selects in their respective divs but still get a validation error or get a persistent value.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has multiple elements with the same name (:airline_name), which is the core problem.  You're on the right track with disabling, but you're disabling the div instead of the select.  I would just do this:

```
// before form is submitted, disable all hidden selects
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  $('select:hidden').prop('disabled', true);
});
```